# Create a bridge that routes to a GRE tunnel

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, virsh

I am trying to create a bridge that routes to a GRE tunnel, which a virtual machine would use.

I have a GRE tunnel setup, but I need a specific virtual machine to use it.
So, I need to create a bridge that points to the GRE tunnel for the virtual machine to use.

I have tried many stuff, but unfortunately none of them have worked.

I am not really a professional at networking, so I am here asking this question.

Comment: Bridges do not route; routers route. Bridges forward frames on the same network (bridging/switching), but routers strip the frames off the packets and forward packets to a different network (routing). Bridging is for traffic on the same network, and routing is for traffic to other networks. In any case, this is not a programming question, so you are asking on the wrong SE site.

Comment: Sorry I phrased it wrong. Is it possible for a bridge to forward traffic to a GRE tunnel?

Comment: As I explained, bridges will bridge frames between devices on the same network. If you are trying to bridge interfaces addressed in different networks, then you need to route, not bridge.

Comment: Also, as I explained, your question is off-topic here. You need to ask on the correct SE site for host configurations, not [so], which is for programming questions.